# Pointer to const object with emplace_back

Tags: c++, stl, constants, c++17, emplace

I don't understand when we can use const variables/objects in collections (particularly with `emplace`). The below code works with const objects directly but not when using pointers to const objects.

```
#include <list>

class MyData {  };

int main() {
    std::list<std::pair<int, MyData>> collection1{};
    std::list<std::pair<int, MyData*>> collection2{};

    const MyData someData{};
    const MyData* someDataPtr = &someData;

    collection1.emplace_back(1, someData);
    //collection2.emplace_back(1, someDataPtr); //Messy template error!
}
```

I assume there's not much advantage to using `emplace_back` over `push_back` for pointers, but I'm using std::pair to illustrate that the other part of the pair could be something big/costly.

Specifically, my question is why does `emplace_back` work with a const object but not a pointer to a const object? Is there a reasonable way to achieve the latter?

For anyone wondering about the use-case, I have a member function which is passed the constituents of the pair, does some processing (but should not change any data) and then emplaces the pair to the collection. Something like:

```
void add_to_schedule(const int id, const MyData* myData) {
   //some processing
   this->collection.emplace_back(id, myData);
}
```

Comment: `*collection2.front() = something;` would modify a const object, and nobody wants that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`const MyData*` can't be converted to `MyData*` implicitly. That means `std::pair<int, MyData*>` can't be constructed from `{1, someDataPtr}` while `someDataPtr` is a `const MyData*`.

Under the same logic,

```
MyData* p = someDataPtr; // fails
MyData m = someData;     // fine
```

As the workaround, you can change `someDataPtr` to `MyData*`, or change the `std::list` to `std::list<std::pair<int, const MyData*>>`.

Comment: So is this about making a copy of a const object is fine (because you have a new object and you can do what you want with it). Making a copy of a pointer to a const object is not (there is no new object, just a new handle to the original const object, so it still can't be modified)?

Comment: @Verwirrt You're right. Make the copy possible means the original object might be modified through the new pointer, which is not expected.

Comment: @Verwirrt technically there is a new object, a pointer is an object. You are right that there isn't another `MyData` object